# Code works in Chrome not in Firefox/Safari

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, safari, compatibility

I'm trying to make a system where you can update the amount of stock you have of a certain product.
I managed to make it function in Chrome but the same script wont function in Firefox/Safari/IE and I can't really figure out why.

```
    <script>
// Post de aanwezige waardes na de database
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var nummer = $("#hetnummer").val();
        var id = $("#hetid").val();
        var inprijs = $("#inprijs").val();
        var verprijs = $("#verprijs").val();
            if (nummer == '' || id == '' ) {
            alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");
        } 
            else {
    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            $.post("php/aanpassen.php", {
                nummer1: nummer,
                id1: id,
                inprijs1: inprijs,
                verprijs1: verprijs,
            }, 
                function(data) {
                // alert(data);
                $('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
            });
            }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a **contentType** issue, so try to set contentType using **ajax function** instead of **post** to **'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'** or **'application/json'**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "php/aanpassen.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
                    nummer1: nummer,
                    id1: id,
                    inprijs1: inprijs,
                    verprijs1: verprijs,
        },
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',// or application/json
        success: function () {   $('#form')[0].reset();},

    });
```

Comment: Tough now it also functions in IE it still doesn't function in Firefox, I did come to the conclusion that it goes wrong in that little part for the Alert does work. Are there any other suggestions or tips to look out for.